# How do I parameterise DRF's API GET url?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I wrote an API with the following regex url format which doesn't conform to what I wanted. How do I go about this? any help is appreciated. Thanks in anticipation.

**What I actually want which throws** `KeyError at /app/check/` `'id'`**error** `...views.py in get_queryset, line 15`

```
http://sample.com/app/check/?id=any_id_passed_into_the_url
```

**What I have that works**:

```
http://sample.com/app/check/id
```

**What I did**

```
# app/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^app/', include('modul.urls', namespace='modul')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


# modul/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from modul.views import OfferView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^check/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', OfferView.as_view(), name='id')
]
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

from app.models import App
from rest_framework import generics
from app.serializers import AppSerializer
from django.http import Http404
from IPython import embed


class OfferView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = AppSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id' # Here is line 15

    def get_queryset(self):
        id = self.kwargs['id']
        try:
            return App.objects.filter(id=id)
        except App.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
```

Comment: But it will not be "REST" anymore. Are you confident with this "parameterization"? Are you sure you have DRF installed? Please show `OfferView` code.

Comment: @Afolabi Olaoluwa Akinwumi  I feel your intention will cause more problems in the future. Suppose what if you forgot to provide the ***`id`*** url param? By default, all those things are handled by DRF and Django very nicely. If you try to change the behavior, you will lose most of the REST features.